# Exporting edmx diagram from edmx designer cut off tables using PDFCreator

Tags: visual-studio-2013, edmx, edmx-designer, pdfcreator

I am trying to export edmx diagram from the edmx designer in Visual Studio 2013 to a png image using [PDFCreator](https://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator). The problem I have is that PDFCreator cut off some tables. In PDFCreator I select ARCH E3 as paper size. Also it is exported to png image using white color as background so cardinality numbers are not observed very well. Below a screenshot.

[image]

So how to:

1. Fit all the edmx diagram into the png without cutting off tables
2. Change png background color to a custom one using PDFCreator so
   cardinality can be correctly observed.

Answer (score 0):

In order cardinality to be observed correctly a workaround is to change visual studio color theme.